# Is performance of Grails 2.0 really that awfully low?

Tags: performance, grails, grails-2.0

I'm somewhat newbie for WEB development based on JVM stack, but future project will require specifically some JVM-based WEB engine. So I started looking on some ground to make things quickly and turned to try Grails. Things looked good from the book, but beeing impressed by really long startup time (grails run-app) I decided to test how this works under load. Here it is:

- test app: follow few instruction here to make it from ground (takes 2 mins assuming you already have Grails and Tomcat installed):

  _http://grails.org/Quick+Start
- test case (with Apache benchmark - comes with Apache httpd - _http://httpd.apache.org):

  ab.exe -n 500 -c _http://localhost:8080/my-project/book/create 
  (Note: this is just displays 2 input fields within styled container)
- hardware: Intel i5 650 (4Core*3.2GHz) 8GB Ram & Win Server 2003 x64

The result is ..

**Grails: 32 Req/Sec**

```
Total transferred:      1380500 bytes
HTML transferred:       1297500 bytes
Requests per second:    32.45 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       308.129 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       30.813 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          87.51 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

(Only 32 Req/Sec with 100% of CPU saturation, this is a way too below my expectations for such hardware)

... Next - i tried to compare it for example with similar dummy JSF application (i took one here: _http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/ - look for "Source code with JAR files", there is \jsf-example2\target\jsf-example2-1.0.war inside),

- test case: ab.exe -n 500 -c 10 _http://localhost:8080/jsf/backend/listing.jsp

The result is ..

**JSF: 400 Req/Sec**

```
Total transferred:      5178234 bytes
HTML transferred:       5065734 bytes
Requests per second:    405.06 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       24.688 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.469 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          4096.65 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

... And finally goes raw dummy JSP (just for reference)

**Jsp: 8000 req/sec:**

```
<html>
<body>
<% for( int i = 0; i < 100; i ++ ) { %>
Dummy Jsp <%= i %> </br>
<% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

```
Total transferred:      12365000 bytes
HTML transferred:       11120000 bytes
Requests per second:    7999.90 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1.250 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.125 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          19320.07 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

...

**Am i missing something?** ... and Grails app can run much better?

PS: I tried profiling my running Grails app with VisualVM, but got endless loop of messages like ...

```
Profiler Agent: Redefining 100 classes at idx 0, out of total 413
...
Profiler Agent: Redefining 100 classes at idx 0, out of total 769
...
```

And finally app just stopped working after few mins - so, looks like profiling Grails is no the choice for good diagnose.

**Update** - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

First of all I have to admin, yes i need to RTFM - i.e. 'grails run-app' is not the correct way to run Grails for performance measurement. After compiling WAR and deploying it to Tomcat performance is not that awfully low - it is just low. The metrics below are for concurrency of 1 user (I just wanted to check what is MAX performance of the framework in one thread and with no heavy load) and while reading other related posts here i came to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819684/jsf-and-spring-performance-vs-poor-jsp-performance" and decided to check Apache Wicket mentioned there - its performance is also included.

Use case is:
- ab.exe -n 500 -c 1 _http://localhost:8080/...
- server is Tomcat7 in vFabric tcServer Dev edition with 'insight' running on background

```
----------------------   tcServer       Plain Tomcat 7    -c 10
/Grails/book/create      77 req/sec     130 req/sec       410 req/sec
/jsf/backend/listing.jsp 133 req/sec    194 req/sec       395 req/sec
/wicket/library/         870 req/sec    1400 req/sec      5300 req/sec
```

So ... anyway there is something wrong with Grails. I have made some profiling using tcServer (thanks Karthick) - it looks like it is able only to trace 'Spring-based' actions and internal stacktrace for Grails is like following (for 2 requests - note: metrics are not stable - i bet accuracy of tcServer far from beeing perfect, but can be used just for inforamtion)

```
Total (81ms)
    Filter: urlMapping (32ms)
        -> SimpleGrailsController#handleRequest (26ms)
        -> Render view "/book/create" (4ms)
    Render view "/layouts/main.gsp" (47ms)

Total (79ms)
    Filter: urlMapping (56ms) ->
        -> SimpleGrailsController#handleRequest (4ms)
        -> Render view "/book/create" (38ms)
    Render view "/layouts/main.gsp" (22ms)
```

PS: it may happen that the root cause for bad performance in Grails are underlying 'Spring' libs, will check this in more details.

Comment: I'd edit your first post since you know your benchmark for Grails is bad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you running it with run-app?

http://grails.org/Deployment states:

"Grails should never be deployed using the grails run-app command as this sets Grails up in "development" mode which has additional overheads. "

Comment: Yes - i *was* running it with 'grails run-app', see my comment for another reply here. However, I'm looking to have my application dynamically updatable even in Prod and it looks like changing *.gsp files under Tomcat does not have any effect. So ... the choice is either run with 'grails run-app' or have a static site :(

Comment: I'd argue that if you want to dynamically update your code in production without a redeployment then you should find another framework / platform.  Grails (and most JVM based frameworks) aren't really designed for that.

Comment: @XtraCoder RTFM [6.2.7 Making Changes to a Deployed Application](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#makingChangesToADeployedApplication)

Comment: @JamesA Good find, don't know that the F is necessary though.

Comment: @typoknig I certainly didn't intend it to be taken in the negative sense just a quick comment with the common abbreviation.  I'll be more careful/sensitive next time.  Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @ubiquibacon The F is for fantastic.

Answer (score 4):

try deploying your sample app to tomcat.  `grails run-app` is for development only.

Comment: _Yep, Grails under Tomcat gives result somewhat close to JSF app - 390req/sec (though with 4 times lower throughput). Still ... is it good enough :)? - in comparison to JSP I expect something around 1000 req/seq would be more appropriate for such a simple page _

Comment: And still no luck with profiling, another message in console, but same result

*** Profiler engine warning: target VM cannot load class to instrument java_lang_Long$getLong
*** probably it has been unloaded recently

Comment: You can try to profile using spring tcServer. This is available as STS bundle as well

Comment: Check out this thread on the user mailing list: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Help-with-a-benchmark-td3943263.html#a3963426 - in particular, disabling the Hibernate OpenSessionInViewInterceptor makes a big difference if you need the extra requests per/s.

Answer (score 2):

in which environment did you start the app? prod? dev?

do you use scaffolding?

i've tried it on my machine (core i7-2600k). a login page with 4 input fields, dynamic layouts and some other things. i've got 525 requests per second in the slower dev environment.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by dev or prod. It is my dev workstation. scaffolding? - yes as far i understand.

Comment: you can start grails in different 'environments'. just run 'grails prod run-app' for production (faster) or 'grails run-app' for development. scaffolding is slow, dont use it on production environments. simple saying: there is a lot of code-generation in the background for every request if you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this is a benchmark by someone who doesn't know alot about grails or his environment; first he is running on Windows know for being bad at resource management which is why most web serves/app serves run in Linux environments.

Second, if he is using 'ab' to benchmark, then he doesn't have his proxy cache setup because after the first hit, the remainder of the hits would be cached and the he is now benchmarking his cache from my understanding of his setup.

So this all just looks like the benchmarking of a bad setup and a poor understanding of Grails. No offense intended.