# grails takes long TTFB time in dev and prod for very first call

Tags: grails, glassfish-4, grails-2.4

I am using grails 2.4.4 and glassfish 4.1 and Java 8.

---

**For Database Call**

When i put a very first request to server it is taking long TTFB time (around 19s).

After that for each request it takes only(around 800 ms)TTFB.

**For Static Pages**

Even for static pages it takes (5 sec)TTFB. and when i refresh page again it takes (80 ms)TTFB.

After first request it loads every page very smoothly in any browser or any machines.(around 80-900 ms). That means it server side problem.

Can anyone tell why this happening.

Is it framework related issue or something else.

Thanks.

Comment: I would start by enabling debugging for DB / cache and generally enabling logging for all the logs warn debug etc - try to capture what it is doing - it could be cache is being initialised - it could be something else - very diffcult to say without knowing exactly what the app is attempting to do as it starts up. I would also test the time after it has started and running for a few minutes vs started just now and lets hit it

Comment: Hi vahid: Sorry for late reply.  I have create new grails application without any changes and made first request (Like http://localhost:8080/TestPerformance/) it has taken 7 second to load page. And When i refresh the same page it has taken only 634ms.

Comment: what processing grails does on loading very first request.? As compare to other application like (JSF), it takes very huge time.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840183/is-performance-of-grails-2-0-really-that-awfully-low